# Why this happend with false ? Whey not right one only?

Tags: javascript, operators

`console.log('Cat' && 'Dog');` // output Dog 
`console.log('Dog' && 'Cat');` // output Cat

`console.log('Cat' && false);` // Output false 
`console.log( false && 'Cat');` // Output false

`console.log('Cat' && true);` // Output true 
`console.log(true && 'Cat');` // Output cat

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` operator evaluates as the left-hand side if the left-hand side value is falsy. Otherwise it evaluates as the right-hand side.

`false` is falsy so you get `false`.

If you want an operator that unconditionally gives you the right-hand side then use [the comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).